# Is it possible get a place object with specific lat and lng?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not sure my question is valid. But I have some requirement like below.

Is it possible get a place object with specific `lat` and `lng`?

In details when we use autocomplete method we can get the place object like: 
 `"place = autocomplete.getPlace();"`.

Is it possible to call `getPlace()` method for specific `lat` and `lng` or any other solution available?

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, what you're asking is called **Reverse Geocoding**.

> **Wiki**:
>
> **Reverse geocoding** is the process of back (reverse) coding of a point
>   location (latitude, longitude) to a readable address or place name.

Yes Google provides reverse geocoding service.  *But it is not a single line which you mentioned in your question.*

It has its own procedure.

Check [**Google's Reverse Geocoding**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) for more information.

You may find the below code useful.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  //  * initialize geocoder class
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885,-73.997383);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function getPlace() {    
  var lat = your Latitude;   // give valid lat
  var lng = your Longitude;  // give valid lng
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
      }
      else {
        //handle error status accordingly
      }
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Hope your understand.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, Hope it will help for me.

Comment: @user1374554 I'm glad that I was able to help.